VS 2022 attaches to android emulator in release build mode
When running release build for android emulator (.net9 maui application with visual studio 2022) the ide still attaches to the emulator and Ide and emulator crash on Stop-Debugging.
I couldn't find any options in my project properties or Tools-Options to change/influence this behaviour.
I also tried:

clean/rebuild solution
delete obj and bin folder
restart IDE

The message when i Stop Debugging:


Does .NET 8.0 also have this problem?

@liyu Yes, also it worked with NET9 just fine until now. So i assumed i would have changed some settings by mistake.

Have you solved the problem ? @Dura

No, unfortunately I couldn't figure out what the Problem is. Still attaches in Release Mode. I also tried create new project, in case it's a setting in my Project but vs 2022 still attaches to the android emulator, no matter what.
